# Restoring a wallet with "G" key

Tags: wallets, ledger-nano

I have XLM on a nano s that is frozen.  I am trying to restore the wallet using my stellar key which starts with a "G".  how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

A Stellar account consists of a keypair with a secret key and a public key. For example, a keypair could look like this:

```
Public Key: GDAKOJZQRBKJAB6GUVFQVDPV5KEAE4J5HDPGYNLIGNZBD433UAHXZU5S
Secret Key: SCVOZH6L45X2CRHHCSREBXHHPWXE56HYR7UUDRRO2EGDNBOBBJDYJ3AU
```

The public key always starts with a "G", and the secret key always starts with an "S".

The secret key is used to sign transactions, without it you won't be able to access your funds.

In other words, what you need to recover is the "S-key", the secret key. The "G-key" is worthless by itself. If you still have your 24 word recovery phrase, then you can use that to recover your wallet, without that, you're unfortunately probably out of luck.

See also:

- https://www.ledger.com/academy/crypto/what-is-a-recovery-phrase
- https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000609933-Lost-device-PIN-code-or-recovery-phrase